# :visible length returning 0 when item is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if statement to check if my div has nothing visible under it, and if so, I hide the siblings of the child element.

```
        var $remainingprojects = $searchproject.show().filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).parents('.srcprojects');

        var $remainingprojectscontainer = $remainingprojects.parents('.projectscontainer');

        $remainingprojects.hide();
        $remainingprojectscontainer.each(function() {
            if($(this).children('.srcprojects:visible').length == 0){//This line
                console.log($(this).children('.projectschildren').html());
                $(this).children('.projectschildren').hide();
                $(this).children('.projectschildren').siblings('.destarrow').hide();
                $(this).children('.projectschildren').siblings('.destproject').hide();
            }
        });
```

It seems to be working, but is still hiding the siblings of the child element for this one:

```
<div class="srcprojects" style=""></div>
```

Everything else that fulfills this condition already has style set to `display:none;` as shown below:

```
<div class="srcprojects" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I have multiple srcprojects under each container. Because it's a search, some or all will be hidden. What I want is for the siblings to be hidden if none of the srcprojects under the container are visible.

Edit: Added surrounding code for context.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I've added the surrounding code for more context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(this).children('.srcprojects').is('visible');
```

**EDIT**

It actually should be this:

```
$(this).children('.srcprojects').is(':visible');
```

This will not work with some inline elements in chrome.

Comment: I have multiple srcprojects under each container. Because it's a search, some or all will be hidden. What I want is for the siblings to be hidden if none of the srcprojects under the container are visible.